# Is it possible to set the a Switchboard callback inside a solana program or only on the client side?

Tags: solana-program

I am reading the docs of the Switchboard vrf, and I am confused. The doc demo shows that the Switchboard vrf is passed from the client instruction, with the callback setted on the client side.
My question is it possible to set the callback inside the solana program. I want to request a random number, and to be called the same program from the callback.

Comment: You want to make a CPI call that will return a random number to use in your program? This is not a good idea and I don't think Switchboard offers this. Check this presentation for details as to why doing random on-chain makes you vulnerable to hackers. https://youtu.be/jW8ep_bmaIw?t=1834